# Logging everything

Tags: javascript, php, logging

I have a problem, i have been given a task to log all events like the Apache server does using our own php logger. I placed the script on all of our pages and everything works good but compared to the Apache log files I miss all the requests that target assets and resources.

Requests like:

```
/assets/some/thing/some.file
```

I can't log. For several days I tried to find answer in the internet but didn't find any.

Using JavaScript is also OK as long as it works.

I am new to web development so if this question has been answered or something known please direct me to the solution.

Comment: @aMrAhD_nAleEhS: I mostly agree with your edits, but please do not use emboldening for names of software products. In English they become proper nouns, and so should just be capitalised. Bold is often overused here anyway - use it sparingly please.

Comment: @halfer sorry English is not my native language... what does emboldening mean?

Comment: That's OK. My message was to an editor of your question - to "embolden" means to **make bold**, like so.

Answer (score 0):

You could try re-routing every asset request to a custom php file which then serves those resources (for example with `mod_rewrite` or a `.htaccess` file). 
You would then be able to log those requests.

Beware though, this could lead to a considerable performance hit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is a hosted website and i dont have access to these files

Comment: I am thinking of finding something like google analitics but free and that i could redirect the data where i want it. Anyone knows anything like that?